# API logic architecture circular dependency

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I've run into a problem with my architecture design. I have a solution with Web API project and a logic library. My idea was to just create an interface in the API project and deal with the implementation in the logic library. So my API project has this interface:

```
public interface IApiCustomerRepository
{
    public Task<Guid> AddCustomerAsync(AddCustomerDTO addCustomerDTO);
    public Task MoveCustomerAsync(MoveCustomerDTO moveCustomerDTO);
}
```

and the implementation is in the logic library. The problem is that I need a project reference from the library to the API but at the same time I need a reference from the API to the library so I can register the service:

```
services.AddTransient<IApiCustomerRepository, ApiCustomerRepository>();
```

Is there a way around this? Or is my approach completely wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of writing the interface in the webapi project, You can use a separate project to write your interface to achieve a three-tier architecture.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I did in the end.